# How to use electron-devtools-installer?

Tags: javascript, electron, developer-tools

### What I have

When it comes to installation and configuration the [official documentation](https://github.com/MarshallOfSound/electron-devtools-installer#usage) states the following:

> All you have to do now is
>
> ```
> import installExtension, { REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS } from 'electron-devtools-installer';
>
> installExtension(REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS)
> .then((name) => console.log(`Added Extension:  ${name}`))
> .catch((err) => console.log('An error occurred: ', err));
> ```

That is a bit concise.

### Questions

- Where should I place this code?
- How should I initialize it?
- How can I add multiple extensions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### tl;dr

Place it in the file where you include Electron and run it after the `ready` event was emitted by it:

```
const { app } = require('electron');
app.on('ready', functionWithTheCodeFromDocs);
```

You only need to do this once! The extensions will persist after this code have been run.

### In depth explanation

#### Install the package

Install the package just like the docs instruct you. In case of npm:

```
npm install electron-devtools-installer --save-dev
```

#### Require the package

You may require the package and configure it in the file where you build up your Electron app. You need to include the installer function and the (possibly multiple) needed extension(s):

With ES6 modules:

```
import installExtension, { REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS, REDUX_DEVTOOLS } from 'electron-devtools-installer';
```

With `require`:

```
const { default: installExtension, REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS, REDUX_DEVTOOLS } = require('electron-devtools-installer');
```

#### Configuration and usage

I will presume that somewhere you required Electron:

```
const { app } = require('electron');
```

The `installExtension` function have to be called after the `ready` event was emitted by the application. If you want to add multiple extensions you have to call the function multiple times with the different extensions by copy-paste:

```
app.on('ready', () => {
    installExtension(REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS)
        .then((name) => console.log(`Added Extension: ${name}`))
        .catch((err) => console.log('An error occurred: ', err));
});
app.on('ready', () => {
    installExtension(REDUX_DEVTOOLS)
        .then((name) => console.log(`Added Extension: ${name}`))
        .catch((err) => console.log('An error occurred: ', err));
});
```

Or you can write a loop:

```
 app.on('ready', () => {
    [REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS, REDUX_DEVTOOLS].forEach(extension => {
      installExtension(extension)
          .then((name) => console.log(`Added Extension: ${name}`))
          .catch((err) => console.log('An error occurred: ', err));
    });
});
```

If you have done everything properly, after you run `electron .` in your project's folder, you should see this in the console:

> Added Extension: React Developer Tools
>   Added Extension: Redux DevTools

**Keep in mind: You only need to run this code once.** As [Electron's `BrowserWindow.addDevToolsExtension` documentation](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#browserwindowadddevtoolsextensionpath) states:

> The extension will be remembered so you only need to call this API once, this API is not for programming use. If you try to add an extension that has already been loaded, this method will not return and instead log a warning to the console.